# SugarCRM Dependencies : Make multiple fields ReadOnly on Dropdown values change

Tags: sugarcrm

I have one dropdown having values Prospecting, Negotiation and Lost.

I have 4 fields on opportunity detailed view(test1, test2, test3, test4).

I want to disable first 2 fields ReadOnly if dropdown value is Negotiation and second 2 fields ReadOnly if dropdown value is Lost.

I have implemented this using dependancies(http://support.sugarcrm.com/Documentation/Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_7.8/Architecture/Sugar_Logic/Dependency_Actions/ReadOnly/).

It works fine for Negotiation but fails when value is Lost.

Comment: Please share the code you have so far.

Comment: Please specify which edition, version you are using.